# The method openOrCreateDatabase(String, int, null) is undefined

Tags: android

I'm trying to open database as follows :

```
SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
myDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("sudoku.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

This code works fine when I implement it in the Service class, but when I try to implement this in the onPostExecute eventhandler of the GeneraterThread class,implementing AsyncTask, I get the following error :

`The method openOrCreateDatabase(String, int, null) is undefined for the type GeneraterThread`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to invoke openOrCreateDatabase method on GeneraterThread instance which doesn't have the method (and Service class has the method). You probably may pass in a reference to a Context object and invoke the method on it. Or use static method of SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase().

Answer (score 7):

It looks like your just set wrong arguments for function.

There are these definitions in SDK:

```
public static SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase (String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler)

public static SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase (String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory)

public static SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase (File file, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory)
```

But your calling that function is wrong.

Maybe you wanted to call `openDatabase (String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int flags)`?

In this case you just set arguments in wrong order - you're doing

```
openOrCreateDatabase("sudoku.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null); //WRONG
```

instead:

```
openDatabase("sudoku.db", null, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //RIGHT
```

Comment: I've seen a ton of examples online like here: http://sree.cc/google/android/creating-sqlite-database-tables-in-android where openOrCreateDatabase is called just like Saurabh Verma is calling it. However, the online documentation only shows these three versions. I'm confused.

Comment: I just discovered there are two different ways of accessing openOrCreateDatabase... through the Context http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html which offers openOrCreateDatabase(String name, int mode, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory) and through SQLiteDatabase http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html which offers the methods Igor describes above.

Comment: But note that parameter "int flags" in SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int flags) is not equivalent to "int mode" in Context method openOrCreateDatabase (String name, int mode, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory).

Answer (score 1):

Use it with your parent class

something like

```
myService.this.openOrCreateDatabase
```

Answer (score 0):

its better use this,

```
db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_PATH_AND_NAME, null);
db.close();
db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_PATH_AND_NAME, null, Context.MODE_APPEND);
```